# NULL terminated c_str()?

Tags: c++, string, null-terminated, c-strings

Why does using `is_it_valid_color("yellow")` work and outputs `FOUND IT` but using `is_it_valid_color(x.c_str());` not work?

I have a feeling it has to do with null terminated strings. The output looks the same in console:

```
color: 'yellow'
FOUND IT
color: 'yellow'
```

.

```
const char *color_names[] = {"yellow", "green", "red"};
const int color_names_SIZE = 3;

void is_it_valid_color(const char* color) {
    cout << "color: '" << color << "'" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < color_names_SIZE; ++i) {
        if(color == *(color_names + i)) {   
            cout << "FOUND IT" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}



is_it_valid_color("yellow");


string x = "yellow";

is_it_valid_color(x.c_str());
```

Comment: Short answer: use `std::string`, and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not comparing strings, you're comparing pointers to strings.

The first one matches because your linker has coalesced the two strings "yellow" to the same physical pointer to save memory. Their addresses therefore compare as the same.

To compare the actual strings themselves, use `strcmp()` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparing memory addresses (in pointers) instead of strings (null terminated sequences of characters) here:

```
if(color == *(color_names + i)) {
```

You need to use `std::strcmp` instead:

```
if(std::strcmp(color, *(color_names + i)) == 0) {
```

Unless you need to for schooling reasons, it's much clearer to use the subscript operator than to use pointer arithmetic.

Also, c_str() is definitely null terminated.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be use the '==' operator to compare to char*'s

instead you should use the strcmp function in the cstring library

```
for(int i = 0; i < color_names_SIZE; ++i) {
    if(strcmp(color,color_names[i]) == 0) {   
        cout << "FOUND IT" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the part of the code, where you (allegedly)compare strings.

And have no doubt, c_str() and a char* are both null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing pointers not strings. Simple fix is to change

```
const char *color_names[] = {"yellow", "green", "red"};
```

to

```
std::string color_names[] = {"yellow", "green", "red"};
```

Try not to use pointers anywhere, they only cause trouble, especially when you are learning. You have enough to learn without adding all the complexities of pointers.

Comment: The project is actually about learning how pointers work, clearly I need to keep learning :)

Comment: OK, well one of the complexities of char* is that sometimes it behaves like a pointer and sometimes it behaves like a string. You were unfortunate in assuming it was behaving like a string when in fact it was being a pointer. If you have to keep using char* then strcmp is the answer as others have said.